# Create explanation log in T-SQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some function in MS SQL Server which returns some calculated value. But I have to get “explanation” for end user how this value was calculated. In other words I have to save to database some calculation log. Could you suggest me the best way to do this?
In T-SQL

I can’t use RCUD (create, update, delete) operations in function.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean Create ,Alter and Drop ?

Comment: No, I mean insert, update, delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite that function as a table-valued functions that returns two columns: the result and the explanation. For example, instead of this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Factorial(@N TINYINT) RETURNS BIGINT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @R BIGINT, @I TINYINT
    SET @R=1  
    SET @I=2
    WHILE @I<=@N BEGIN
        SET @R=@R*@I
        SET @I=@I+1
    END
    RETURN @R  
END

GO
SELECT dbo.Factorial(5)
```

You can write another function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FactorialExplained(@N TINYINT) 
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Result bigint, Explanation nvarchar(1000))
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @R BIGINT, @I TINYINT, @E nvarchar(1000)
    SET @R=1  
    SET @I=2
    SET @E='1'
    WHILE @I<=@N BEGIN
        SET @R=@R*@I
        SET @E=@E+'*'+CONVERT(varchar(3),@I)
        SET @I=@I+1
    END
    INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (@R, @E)
    RETURN
END

GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.FactorialExplained(5)
```

Razvan

Comment: Thank you. It's interesting idea. Although I expected many strings "explanation" of behavior of my function I think I could manage this inconvenience.